# How to write a Proper SQL Connection String?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, connection-string

Using VB 6 and Sql Server 2000.

In my code I am using open dialog control for selecting the database file, once I selected the database(Dual_ACS.mdf) file, it will appear in the textbox (path and filename)

Textbox name = databasetext

My code.

```
Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & UName & ";Password=" & PWord & ";InitialCatalog=DUAL_ ACS; Data Source=" & databasetext & ""
Cn.Open
```

But it is showing error. How to write a Proper SQL Connection String?

Need VB 6 code help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data Source in a SQLOLEDB connection needs to point to the SQL Server Server and Instance Name ( or IP but then you need to specify the port).  See [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server#6) for specifics.
You can't point directly to the mdf file.  This isn't access.

If you want the users to be able to select a data source you should use the Universal Data Link dialog built-in to ADO.  Here is an example pulled from a larger class I use.  You need to add a reference to the "Microsoft OLE DB Service Component 1.0 Type Library" or C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ole db\oledb32.dll.
If you just need to see what the connection string will look like yourself just create a file called test.udl and then double click it.  The interface used there is the same one invoked in this code.

```
' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Edit
'
' Description:
'    Edits the udl
'
' Arguments:
'
' Dependencies:
'    MSDASC.DataLinks.PromptEdit
'    MSDASC.DataLinks.PromptNew
'
' History:
' 05/23/2003 - WSR : Created
'
Public Function Edit() As Long

Dim dlgEdit       As MSDASC.DataLinks
Dim strConnection As String

   Set dlgEdit = New MSDASC.DataLinks

   ' if there is a connection string
   If Len(m_conSource.ConnectionString) > 0 Then

      ' prompt user to edit the connection
      If Not dlgEdit.PromptEdit(m_conSource) Then

         ' if they didn't edit the connection string
         ' return error code
         Edit = -1

      End If

   ' if there is no connection string
   Else

      ' prompt user to create new connection
      On Error Resume Next
      strConnection = dlgEdit.PromptNew()

      ' if there was a connection string created
      If Len(strConnection) > 0 Then

         ' use it
         m_conSource.ConnectionString = strConnection

      ' if there was no connection string created
      Else

         ' return error code
         Edit = -1

      End If

   End If

   Set dlgEdit = Nothing

End Function
' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 11):

There is an entire website dedicated to this subject: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: +1: Don't know if it will help with the original person's question precisely, but it is the right answer for people searching and finding this question in general.

Answer (score 7):

If you're sure it's the connection string, check [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) - it has the proper formats for hundreds of connection strings.  It's a great reference.

Are you sure it's the connection string though?  Why don't you tell us what the error message is?  And what version of SQL Server are you using?